# Web front end running behind nginx not able to query API

Tags: api, nginx

I have a web front-end code running behind nginx  which queries an API running on the same host on port 8080 , but the console logs show a :

> GET http://sysops1.env.tools.com:8080/getblacklist net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

while the curl requests are working fine .

What am I missing here ?

Edit :

the frontend code is placed under /var/www/ipblock and also I have added this to my nginx config to allow proxying :

> ```
>    location /ipblock {
>             proxy_pass http://sysops1.env.tools.com:8080/getblacklist;
> ```
>
> }

Anything that needs to be modified in the nginx config .

Comment: Is this GET happening in the browser. If so, it needs to use port 80, not 8080. Port 8080 would ordinarily be blocked from outside.

Comment: I'm guessing your code is generating a self referencing url somewhere, and it's getting the port wrong because nginx isn't fixing the port header. You could look at some other way to generate the self referencing url, which is proxy aware, or change the nginx config to fix the port header.

Comment: @user1751825 this is what request is being generated from the front-end code :                                                                                                            $.get( "http://sysops1.env.com:8080/getblacklist", function( data ) {

                $('.block_list_table').DataTable( {

               data: (data && data.Block_list && data.Block_list.Arr_Block_list) || {},

Comment: @user1751825 thanks for the suggestion to check port 8080 connectivity from outside . That was the issue .